# Could the gold actually kill Smaug?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, smaug, desolation-of-smaug

This wasn't in the book, so I was wondering: in the second *Hobbit* movie (*The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug*), when:

> the dwarves covered Smaug with liquefied gold

could he actually die?

Comment: They weren't trying to kill Smaug - they were trying to change his alignment.

Comment: **<comments removed>** Leave the spoiler for an unrelated work out of the question, please.

Comment: The existing answers focus on whether the heat would kill him, but I wonder if the idea was actually to *encase* him in liquid gold, let it harden, and then have a big, more or less trapped dragon to deal with, which is a slightly less formidable opponent than a regular dragon.  Even if the coat of gold only lasted a few minutes, you would have a bit of time to try and smash/stab him to death before he broke out.

Comment: That whole sequence with Smaug chasing the dwarves looked like a "Tom & Jerry" short...

Comment: @Stone True - lol yes, and not unlike Tom & Jerry shorts, that whole scene more or less emphasized the incompetence of Smaug the same way Tom looks incompetent by being so easily fooled and thwarted every single time. Kind of makes you wonder what took people so long to take the mountain back when a hand full of Dwarves having been out of combat for so long just waltz in and slapstick their way out of death from what is touted as one of the most dangerous creatures alive... who happens to kill exactly zero of them. The book isn't so silly, but still the same general thing happens.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have not found any good picture illustrating it yet (contributions are welcome), but in the movie Smaug's belly skin shows visible glowing cracks every time he prepares to breath fire (which is in itself quite a nice cue that you want to run or hide very fast).

This indicates that his fire is not only some kind of flammable gas he only lights up in his mouth, but rather some kind of internal flame he needs to focus and channel before using it.

His inner parts have, indeed, to be very fire resistant, since dragon fire is described as so hot as to be one of the only means to destroy rings of power in the *Fellowship of the Ring*: That's the way four of the dwarven rings met their fate.

Wondering if this resistance is magical or natural is kind of pointless, since for Tolkien magic is some kind of power or quality native to all beings, in varying amounts depending of their kind, often used quite subtly and involuntary (for more information, see the [can-the-elves-do-magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8864/can-the-elves-do-magic) question).

Considering the amount of fire-resistance (more than melting metal temperature 1,948°F) which is then required from his inner parts, a bath of molten gold does not seem that harmful anymore for any fire-breathing dragon...

Comment: +1. It's worth noting, though, that there's no indication that Smaug is immune to drowning or suffocation.  If he had inhaled when he was submerged, or if the gold had cooled fast enough to trap him or prevent him from breathing, he likely would have died.

Comment: @Nerrolken Indeed, and there is no need to wait this long: Considering the density of gold, he should probably have been crushed by the liquid wave itself... Apparently, Tolkien's dragons are made of very tough stuff :)

Comment: @Nerrolken In fact, that's closer to what happens in the book. Getting shot doesn't (directly) kill Smaug, falling in the lake does.

Answer (score 38):

It might actually kill Smaug, though for completely different reasons than what the movie scene suggests.

---

As already said, the temperature of molten gold should hardly be impressive to a fire-drake – which does however not imply that they can necessarily cope with getting completely immersed in it.

**But**, it's rather absurd that Smaug ever sinks in the gold in the first place! Though [movies almost always get it wrong<sup>***TVTropes warning!***</sup>](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodDensity), gold is really really dense. The linked page actually points out that

> Gollum shouldn't have sunken in the lava of Mount Doom

since rock, liquid or not, is much denser that water/biomass. This applies far more strongly to gold: even if Smaug's body was solid [lead (11 g·cm<sup>−3</sup>)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead), *he would easily float on liquid* [*gold* (19 g·cm<sup>−3</sup>)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold)! If his body instead had a density comparable to ordinary life forms, he should pretty much be able to *walk* on it. (Only ≈1/20 of the body needs to be immersed to lift the rest. An actual elephant might be able to do this, as long as it would stand the heat – which it might conceivably do for a few seconds: unlike in the rather hotter (and closer to [blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)) case of lava, radiation heating isn't that effective for liquid gold; it would at first only sear the elephant's legs by direct heat transfer.)

---

Then again, the high density has another consequence. Even if you hit water at sufficiently high speeds, the impact on the surface will kill you.<sup>[Yes, TVTropes also has a page on that subject](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SoftWater).</sup> Apply that to gold, and the result is that if you fall from some height on liquid gold the surface isn't merely "as hard as concrete", but in fact "harder"! And, again contrary to what movies sometimes say, mechanical crushing becomes ever *more* of a problem, the larger you go, due to the [square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law). So, if an elephant were to *fall* onto a lake of gold from, say, 10 metres height, then it would probably die immediately, simply from the shock of hitting the surface.

This doesn't directly apply to the movie scene, since Smaug sits on the ground in front of the liquid-gold statue before it collapses. However, this sheer mechanical power of the high-density liquid *would* pose a very real problem for any creature in that position: the disintegrating dwarf statue would constitute a tsunami wave that would push stuff out of its way much more powerfully than a comparable water wave. It would not drown the dragon, but push it towards the opposite wall with incredible speed. Impact on that wall then might be rather deadly indeed, certainly for an elphant, man or whatever non-magical creature.

Evidently, dragons have mechanical powers unlike any real lifeform: otherwise they couldn't possibly fly. So they might, in fact, survive a gold tsunami. But at least, the dwarves weren't quite so unrealistic if they hoped in fact to *crush* the dragon on the opposite wall by that means, rather than actually drowning it in the gold.

Comment: Lava is not necessarily hotter [(800 °C - 1,200 °C)](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=how+hot+is+lava) than the [melting point of gold (1,064 °C)](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=melting+point+of+gold). It certainly is not *much* hotter. [Magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma) can be hotter with a normal range from 700 °C to 1300 °C with some compositions as low as 600 °C and high as 1600 °C.

Comment: @Makyen: interesting! I would have estimated the typical temperature of lava as rather hotter, and the melting point of gold rather cooler – something like 1400 °C vs 800 °C. I should have looked that up. The reason for my misestimate would be that gold is much more reflective than rock, therefore it doesn't behave like a black-body at all: at the same temperature, it radiates much less intensely! This means both that its temperature is easily underestimated, and that it's less dangerous than lava – i.e., the point I was making still kind of holds, though for a different reason.

Comment: A question is also whether his skin needs to let oxygen through. He would not have been the first to die from being painted gold. Has happened in the real world.

Comment: @MishaRosnach: yeah, though, if the gold never gets to touch a significant portion of his skin (which as I argued it likely won't) then this point doesn't apply.

Comment: "Beware the dragon with the touch of gold... that touch is cold!"

Comment: @Ber at least he doesn't have a golden gun.

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen this scene, but I don't really understand this answer. You state that Smaug is sitting in front of a statue before being hit by a wave of molten gold. This seems consistent with my vague memory that Smaug is *covered* in gold instead of *falling into* a pool of gold. Doesn't this make the entire discussion about surface tension and density irrelevant?

Comment: @KyleStrand I never said anything about surface tension. The point I did make is that a wave of gold is to an animal like a water wave is to a piece of styrofoam or cork: that floats to the crest so easily that the wave doesn't have a chance to bury it underneath. The only chance to bury something in gold is to drop it from directly above.

Comment: @leftaroundabout You discussed "floating" on gold; whether or not something "floats" is determined by density *and* surface tension, not density alone, even if you only mentioned density. In any case, looking at the scene on youtube, it still seems reasonable to me that the wave would break around Smaug and cover him rather than pushing or lifting him. Whether it's realistic that he falls over because of this is perhaps another matter, but I'm still not sure that the high density of molten gold is enough to demonstrate that the scene is physically implausible.

Comment: @KyleStrand so _you're not sure_ that the high density has the effects I claim. Well, fair enough, I may be wrong. But pray, what leads you to think this way, apart from the fact that _any liquid depicted by Holywood or Peter Jackson_ behaves like water?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well, simply the fact that, as I said, surface tension is part of this equation, as well as that the cork analogy seems completely incompatible with what's actually on screen. This is a fairly interesting question I wouldn't mind seeing an analysis of on Physics.SE or somewhere, and I don't know enough about liquid dynamics to give a definitive answer, but the behavior of the gold in the movie is reasonable assuming that molten gold flows and disperses fairly quickly.

Comment: @KyleStrand well, why not – this seems a question you could well ask on Physics.SE.

Comment: Posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/339387/41033

Comment: @MishaRosnach There's no such thing as death by "skin asphyxiation". We're not frogs; we don't breathe through our skin. http://www.snopes.com/movies/films/goldfinger.asp

Comment: @JacobC. Fair enough, although Smaug is considerably more closely related to a frog than we are.  Still, not likely to have skin breath.  As a side note, I think if we could breathe through our skin, we would still not be frogs.

Comment: @MishaRosnach His relation to frogs is debatable -- it's not stated in the Silmarillion what Glaurung was bred from, and real evolutionary cladistics doesn't necessarily apply to Arda. (Also, in the real world, our separation from frogs -- in terms of millions of years since last common ancestor -- is the same as any reptile's, since our synapsid ancestors and the sauropsid ancestors of extant reptiles diverged after the branching off from amphibians.)

Granted, skin-breathing wouldn't require us to be frogs. Being transformed into frogs would be one route toward that condition, however. ;)

Comment: @JacobC. Probably true, especially since I don't remember any specific references to Smaug being a reptile anyway.  Just Googled a bit, and couldn't find specific info, other than a real-life African lizard species called Smaug.  To which I thought "well, there's a clue," but then read that the lizard was named after Tolkien's Smaug, and not the other way around. 
 That said, Middle Earth is supposedly located on actual Earth, so I'm sure the speciation can of worms must have been opened many times about it.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Correct. And Smaug's original name happens to be what I'm using - Pryftan. Apparently a lot of things are named after Tolkien's works though and iirc that includes species. A mountain range (this I remember) on Titan is named after Mount Doom. Pretty sure recently I saw a list of things named after Tolkien's works but I can't be sure of that. Glaurung was called the Great Worm amongst other things but I don't know the etymology of that (maybe that he had no wings is part of it?). I don't have any recollection of anything to do with frogs but I certainly could have missed it.

Comment: @Pryftan Well, worm comes from wyrm, which is a term still sometimes used in fantasy when talking about dragons. And wyrm is Germanic, used to refer to snakes, reptiles, etc. From there it wormed its way into Old English, so it's no surprise Tolkien grabbed it. He did like that Old English.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Right. As soon as you wrote 'wyrm' I thought immediately of German and you're of course absolutely right. And thanks for the punning; that's something that is always very welcome but esp today.

Comment: @Pryftan Every day is a wonderful day for puns.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Couldn't agree more! I very often pun and I very often note puns to people whether they meant it or not.

Answer (score 9):

Smaug, based on his description and key characteristics, is identifiable as a winged "fire-drake" (of the same ilk as Ancalagon the Black) rather than a "cold-drake" or "long-worm".

Given that the breath of a "fire-drake" burned hot enough to destroy a Ring of Power (four of the Seven were lost in this way) and that one "fire-drake" (Ancalagon the Black, mightiest of them) crushes a volcanic peak without Tolkien even bothering to mention the word lava (hotter by far than liquid gold) I think it is safe to assume that Smaug, being a particularly mighty "fire-drake" (a "most specially strong worm" and in fact "the greatest of the dragons of his day"), would be completely unconcerned by molten gold

This scene, I fear, is another instance of needless Hollywood-style dramatics that at best lack grounding and at worst contradict Middle-Earth canon.

Comment: **Contradict canon????** How dare they!! Kill them all immediately!!

Comment: @Daft if you'll forgive me - PJ is rather daft. Not insulting you, mind, but merely punning.

Answer (score 3):

The melting point of gold is 1064 degrees Celsius, which is not really all that hot in the grand scheme of the maximum temperatures that medieval style furnaces could operate at (to get molten iron you need 1200 degrees, glass is even higher, steel is 1500+ etc).  This is well within the reach of a good human smith (and certainly a master dwarf blacksmith) with a good permanent furnace *in universe* I would imagine.

So, on the basis that humans and even dwarves could not unmake the rings through fire you would have to imagine that they were simply unable to generate enough heat in their furnaces, yet a dragon could.  Let's imagine that you need at least twice as high a temperature as man would manage to melt a ring of power, just for arguments sake, that's a temperature of roughly 3000 degrees assuming steel is the hottest thing man could smelt.

Take into account that a dragon *could*, and that the dragon fire they could use to destroy a ring would by definition be *considerably higher* than what man/dwarf could produce (and you would imagine that their internal temperatures would have to be even higher than that of their flames) then this sort of thing, whilst no doubt *uncomfortable, painful, restrictive* etc, is not a mortal danger to a dragon, being simply *not all that hot* (a third of the *minimum* temperature they were capable of producing externally) from the dragons perspective.

Comment: But then consider that lava ranges from 700 to 1,200 °C  at it's hottest, while Iron and Steel is melted at higher temperatures, it all falls apart. Unless Middle Earth volcanos are significantly hotter or Middle Earth Metals have different physical properties and melting points, you need to adjust for **magic, not raw temperature.**

Comment: @cde Good points. I'd probably expand by saying a) the internals of a magma chamber would probably be far in excess of what Lava can be when it's managed to get *outside*, but also b) It might not be that *volcanos* are hotter in Middle Earth, but perhaps that *Mount Doom* specifically is hotter.  It would be interesting to follow through whether the ring must be destroyed in Mt Doom because *that's where it was made*, or because that's the only place hot enough to make or subsequently un-make it.  Would another volcano work?  *Are there* any others?

Comment: If you want to talk about "twice as high of a temperature," you should be using an absolute scale i.e. Kelvin.

Answer (score 2):

Dragons are magical creatures, and in Tolkien's works, magic is not based on rules and spells - it is always inherent to people/creatures or objects, and its effects are not well defined or predictable. Conventional physics, chemistry or biology on the other hand, are routinely ignored.

So I think it would be consistent with the way Tolkien wrote his stories to assume that
since dragons are creatures of fire, they are at least resistant to fiery things like liquid gold and unlikely to be killed by it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we believe it makes sense for the gold to neatly fall around Smaug and cover him (which is addressed by the other answers), the problem in the plan is that the pool of gold with Smaug inside couldn't solidify fast enough.

If Smaug could be trapped in a pool of solid gold, he would probably die or stop being a threat anyway.

I've always wondered how much water it would have taken to cool down all that gold. Presumably the dwarves could have emptied a nearby lake, filled the next room with water or whatever, and flooded the gold pool at the same time.

If we assume that the gold was at 1100 °C, a bit above the melting point, that the nearby water is at 20 °C, and that we want to reduce the gold to a mere 100 °C without turning all the water into steam, we can divide the [latent heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat) and [specific heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) of the gold by the specific heat of the water, which in [in kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-change_material#Common_PCMs) would make:

( 63.72 kJ/kg + (1100-100 °C) * 0.129 kj/kg-K ) / ( ( 100-20 °C ) * 4.186 kJ/kg-K ) = 0.575

So it would take less than 0.6 kg of water for every 1 kg of gold. Liquid [gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold) is approximately 17.3 times as dense as water, so that neatly translates to about 10 m³ of water for every 1 m³ of gold.

It's not clear how much gold there is, but the gold pool is shown to neatly fill the bottom of the hall, which is shown a moment before to have just 6 steps. So maybe 2 meters? (Absurd that Smaug fits in just 2 meters of height.) In which case you'd need to fill the room with some 20 m of water.

The [heat of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization#Other_common_substances) for water is a fancy 2257 kJ/kg, or 6.7 times what the specific heat gives us above, so if we let all the water go into steam then you "only" need a volume of water 3 times as big as the gold. You'd definitely have to escape quick enough to avoid getting quickly cooked like vermicelli rice in a steam cooker...

Comment: So, could it kill Smaug or not? You’ve gone into some nice analysis of if the actual gold melting/solidifying part is possible but you’ve not really answered the question if I’m reading it correctly.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thanks for the comment. I made it more explicit now. It also depends on whether Smaug can do without breathing and/or can produce fire while engulfed in gold.

Answer (score -2):

he did show signs of pain, but probably more along the lines of one of us dumb humans sticking their hand in hot water straight out of the facet, 'ouch it stings and burns and its bloody hot' but the worst we really end up with is reddened skin unless of course it happens to be boiling/scalding... which it was probably on the lesser end for Smaug the awesome.

so yeah, it just pissed him off more than he already was.

Comment: This looks more like a comment then an answer.  It does not actually provide an answer to the question.